# Is it possible to project texture across object instances with Animation Nodes?

Tags: uv, animation-nodes, instances

I'm trying to project a logo texture across a grid of instances so that I can control it's movement with the Object Controller Falloff node.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish that was just done with a bunch of separate cube objects without Animation Nodes. 
[image: First Example - Separate Cubes]

When trying to place the UV texture on the instanced objects using Animation Nodes, it applies the texture to each cube separately like below. 
[image: 2nd Example - Animation Nodes]

Is there are way to project the texture across all the cubes like the first example using Animation Nodes?

At the very least, is there a way I can use the the Object Controller Node as an effector on the separate cube objects so that they move the same way as they would if they were instanced? I've tried using translation matrices to move them but they don't snap back into place after I move the effector away like the instanced objects do...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fragment position as you texture coordinates as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Alternatively, you can make the instances as a single object as follows:

[image: Node Tree 2]

Comment: Thank you @OmarAhmad!! The texture did project how I wanted after following your steps. However, when using the falloff past a certain point, the texture disappears from the cubes. The texture also resets/re-centers on the cube after falloff instead of just pushing out the portion of the texture it's falling over and repeats at the top of the grid. Here's a link to an example: https://imgur.com/a/W8Xt4 Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @CheyJax Can you show me the material and AN nodes trees?

Comment: Here you go! https://imgur.com/a/UhPUa (Material Nodes) - https://imgur.com/a/Bk0qZ (Animation Nodes) Thanks!

Comment: @CheyJax The second node tree (Which you used) uses the generated output from texture coordinates node and not the position as the first node tree.
Also, notice that my objects are lying on the xy plane, while yours are lying on the zx plane, so you have to rotate it.

Comment: Thank you!! @OmarAhmad - The texture coordinate output did the trick! Thanks again for all your help and patience. You're awesome! :-)